# jQuery eq() selector not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've tried every possible combination that I could find but it still doesn't work. I'm trying to select the first, second, third... images and change the CSS properties.

The JavaScript:

```
    $("#slider:eq(0)")filter(img).css("display","none");
    $("#slider:eq(0)")filter(img).css("visibility","hidden");
```

The HTML:

```
    <div id  = "slider">
    <img id = "slider_img5" class = "slider_image" src = "img/slider_image_5.png" width = "1000px" height = "400px" alt = "slider_image_5">
    <img id = "slider_img4" class = "slider_image" src = "img/slider_image_4.png" width = "1000px" height = "400px" alt = "slider_image_4">
    <img id = "slider_img3" class = "slider_image" src = "img/slider_image_3.png" width = "1000px" height = "400px" alt = "slider_image_3">
    <img id = "slider_img2" class = "slider_image" src = "img/slider_image_2.png" width = "1000px" height = "400px" alt = "slider_image_2">
    <img id = "slider_img1" class = "slider_image" src = "img/slider_image_1.png" width = "1000px" height = "400px" alt = "slider_image_1">
    </div>
```

The CSS:

```
#slider{
position : absolute;
height : 400px;
width : 100%;
border-radius : 3px;
-moz-border-radius : 3px;
box-shadow : 1px 1px 5px #bbbbbb;
-moz-box-shadow : 1px 1px 5px #bbbbbb;
}

.slider_image{
position : absolute;
top : 0px;
left : 0px;
border-radius : 3px;
-moz-border-radius : 3px;
}

#slider_img1 , #slider_img2 , #slider_img3 , #slider_img4{
visibility : hidden;
display : none;
}
```

I hope someone can help me.

**UPDATE 1**

Thank you for all the answers but none of them work. I'm calling the function on document ready and it is definitely called (tested with `alert();` ). I also preset the styles of all images so they are all hidden except for the first one.

**UPDATE 2**

Sorry guys, there was a semicolon missing. Thank you for all the help!

Comment: With these tags? Sorry but could you be a little bit more specific which tags you mean?

Comment: No. The only thing I want to do is change the visibility of one image when the page loads. Then wait for a second and change the visibility of another one...

Comment: If I wanted to use a plugin I would have used it. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need a space between `#slider` and `:eq(0)`.

Without the space, it's looking for an element `#slider` that *is* the first, instead of the  first *descendant* of `#slider`.

Note however, that `:eq` is a [jQuery extension](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) to selectors.  For better performance you should use `$('#slider img').eq(n)`, allowing the entire (valid) CSS selector to be parsed as quickly as possible, and then using `.eq` to get the element you want.

Alternatively, use the native CSS `:nth-child()` syntax instead, i.e. `#slider :nth-child(1)`, but note that this uses numbers starting from 1 instead of 0.

Also, your `filter(img)` syntax as given is incorrect.  It should be chained (i.e. `.filter`) and the parameter should be a valid selector, i.e. `'img'` (with the quotes).  However if your real HTML is as shown you don't need the filter because it's a NoOp - the previous function call can only return images.

Comment: well, what's the `filter(img)` supposed to do?  Did you perhaps mean `.filter('img')`?  If so, you can omit it because the only children are images.

Comment: What I want to do, is to change the visibility of the first image and wait for a second then do the same for the second image ... I want to build a slider basically

Answer (score 2):

Ok, you can do this with CSS. From what I understand, you want to display the first image, and hide the others? So add:

```
#slider_img5{
  visibility : visible;
  display : block;
}
```

or

```
#sider img:first-child{
  /* same... */
}
```

The `visibility` property is unnecessary here because you're already hiding the element with `display: none` ...

Comment: Or if you want to stick with classes, `$("#slider .slider_image:eq(0)")...`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$('#slider img').eq(0).hide();
```

There's really no need to set `visibility: hidden` once `display: none` is already set. But that's more or less what `.hide()` does.

Comment: @a13ks Note in your example you're using the [`eq: selector`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) and in this example it's the [`eq() method`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

Comment: @Boaz: `:eq()` isn't a standard CSS selector, so it can't be fed into `querySelectorAll`, which is implemented natively.

Comment: I completely agree. In this context, I meant a *jQuery* selector, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Should be using `.find` instead of `.filter`.

```
.find('img').css("display","none");
```